# Is there any 'web-based' sql test environment with a test database loaded?

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there any 'web-based' sql test environment with a test database loaded, like STUDENTS DB classic sample?

I find this two sites, but none of them has a DB sample precharged:

https://sqltest.net/

http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Oracle's Live SQL](https://livesql.oracle.com) is pre-loaded with the following test tables:

```
SELECT OWNER, TABLE_NAME
FROM   ALL_TABLES
WHERE OWNER NOT IN ( 'SYS', 'SYSTEM', 'MDSYS', 'ORDDATA', 'CTXSYS', 'ORDSYS' )
ORDER BY OWNER, TABLE_NAME;

OWNER   TABLE_NAME
------- ---------------
AD      AD_ACADEMIC_SESSION
AD      AD_DEPARTMENTS
AD      AD_EXAM_TYPE
AD      AD_FACULTY_DETAILS
AD      AD_JOBS
AD      AD_PARENT_INFORMATION
AD      AD_STUDENT_COURSE_DETAILS
AD      AD_STUDENT_DETAILS
AV      GEOGRAPHY_DIM
AV      PRODUCT_DIM
AV      SALES_FACT
AV      TIME_DIM
DD      DD_DEQUEUE_ERRORS
DD      DD_DINOSAURS
DD      DD_LOCATIONS
DD      DD_MEMBERS
DD      DD_MESSAGES
DD      DD_SEED_DATA
DD      DD_SETTINGS
DD      DD_TEMPLATES
HR      COUNTRIES
HR      DEPARTMENTS
HR      EMPLOYEES
HR      JOBS
HR      JOB_HISTORY
HR      LOCATIONS
HR      REGIONS
OE      CATEGORIES_TAB
OE      CUSTOMERS
OE      ORDERS
OE      ORDER_ITEMS
OE      PRODUCT_INFORMATION
OLYM    OLYM_ATHLETES
OLYM    OLYM_ATHLETE_GAMES
OLYM    OLYM_BASE_EVENTS
OLYM    OLYM_DISCIPLINES
OLYM    OLYM_EVENTS
OLYM    OLYM_GAMES
OLYM    OLYM_MEDALS
OLYM    OLYM_NATIONS
OLYM    OLYM_SPORTS
SCOTT   DEPT
SCOTT   EMP
SH      CAL_MONTH_SALES_MV
SH      CHANNELS
SH      COSTS
SH      COUNTRIES
SH      CUSTOMERS
SH      DIMENSION_EXCEPTIONS
SH      FWEEK_PSCAT_SALES_MV
SH      PRODUCTS
SH      PROMOTIONS
SH      SALES
SH      SUPPLEMENTARY_DEMOGRAPHICS
SH      TIMES
WORLD   WORLD_POPULATION
```

Answer (score 2):

Apart from APEX I know these ones:

- http://sqlfiddle.com/
- http://rextester.com/l/oracle_online_compiler
- http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2

However, they are all empty. You would have to create tables by your own.

Answer (score 1):

Sure; register at [apex.oracle.com](https://apex.oracle.com/en/) and you'll have it.

Apart from you being able to create Apex pages, there's the **SQL Workshop** which lets you browse & query those tables.